# function onOpen() of sideNav is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm using materializecss , That is the sideNav initialization, but onOpen property is not working.

```
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
         menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
         edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
         closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
         draggable: true, // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens,
         onOpen: function() { alert('Open'); },// A function to be called when sideNav is opened
         onClose: function() { alert('Closed'); }// A function to be called when sideNav is closed
  });
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Any errors in the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`)?

Comment: Does not run onOpen, does nothing, and does not give me error in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug because when I updated to the latest version of Materialize (0.100.2) this problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added on May 31 in the v0.100.2 version.

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/commit/8a01666817bd6f6f69b7a5b08b1a3f1d1677f1ee

Also, if you do not wish to update to the new version, the show function triggers a click on the side-nav button, and the hide function triggers a click on $('#sidenav-overlay')

Answer (score -1):

This does work but you cant see the alert on a mobile sized screen.
If you use `console.log("Open");` instead of `alert("Open");` you will be able to see it (but in the console).